# Analytic Solution for the Minimum of a function

Tags: optimization, maxima-minima

I'm looking for the minimum of the function ($n$, $o$, and $s$ are all constants greater than $0$):

$$f(x)=\sqrt{\frac{1}{4}n^{2}o^{2}*\left(n*x+x-\frac{2*ln(x)}{ln(2)}\right)^{2}+\frac{n^{2}s^{2}*ln(x)^{2}}{ln(2)^{4}}}$$

I can find a numerical answer for a given $n$, $s$, and $o$, but not an analytic solution.

I've tried taking the derivative with respect to $x$, which is:

$$\frac{\frac{n^{2}o^{2}\left(-\frac{2}{ln\left(2\right)*x}+n+1\right)\left(-\frac{2ln\left(x\right)}{ln\left(2\right)}+nx+x\right)}{2}+\frac{2n^{2}s^{2}ln\left(x\right)}{ln\left(2\right)^{4}*x}}{2\sqrt{\frac{n^{2}o^{2}\left(-\frac{2ln\left(x\right)}{ln\left(2\right)}+nx+x\right)^{2}}{4}+\frac{n^{2}s^{2}ln\left(x\right)^{2}}{ln\left(2\right)^{4}}}}$$

and then tried to solve for:

$$\frac{n^{2}o^{2}\left(-\frac{2}{ln\left(2\right)*x}+n+1\right)\left(-\frac{2ln\left(x\right)}{ln\left(2\right)}+nx+x\right)}{2}+\frac{2n^{2}s^{2}ln\left(x\right)}{ln\left(2\right)^{4}*x}=0$$

Again I can find a numerical solution for a given $n$, $s$, and $o$ but I can't find an analytic solution for $x$.

Does an analytic solution even exist, and if it does what is it/how would I find it?

Comment: have you any values for the parameters?

Comment: looks like a transcendental equation with logs and x's -- unless parameters take a special set of values

Comment: $g(x) = \sqrt{f(x)}$ will have extrema only when $f'(x)=0$, which simplifies your problem slightly. Also, don't use $o$ as a parameter, its bad style.

Comment: I highly doubt this helps, but I know that x will range from [0, 1) and that n will be an integer, and that n, o, and s will all be greater than 0.

Comment: i think your derivative is not correct